# not all code paths return a value but in any case there is value return

Tags: c#

I just learned Method Declaring and i don't know too much how to use it, i tried to make an algorithm that takes 2 numbers and return their smallest common divide, and if there is no common divider, return -1, thats the code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static int Div(int a, int b)
        {
            int max = Math.Max(a, b);
            bool div = false;
            for(int i = 2; i <= max / 2; i++)
            {
                if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
                {
                    return i;
                    div = true;
                    i = max;
                }

            }
            if (div == false)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 2 Numbers");
             int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(Div(num, num2));

        }
    }
```

it tells me that there is an unreachable code, and not all code paths return a value, but why? if i get 2 numbers that does have a commong divider it will return it, and if not it will return -1, no execptions I think, thanks in advance

Comment: `div = true;
                    i = max;` is unreachable due to being after the `return`. These lines can never be executed.

Comment: Your `Div` function is not guaranteed to return a value.  It is possible that neither of the `return` statements is reached.

Comment: You have a couple of issues... firstly in your for loop, the code after the return statement won't be reached because the return statement will stop further processing within the function and return the value of `i`.

Secondly, if the condition in your for loop isn't met, you don't need to wrap your final return in a condition, which is what's throwing the compiler. The compiler isn't aware that div will definitely be false, so is warning you that there's a chance that nothing is returned from the function - remove the condition and that issue will go away.

Comment: @Amy No, technically it's not possible, because `div` will never be set to `true`, and so the final `if` is never false.  Of course, the compiler cannot reason as such, hence the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not clever enough. But the last `if` is redundant anyway because it's always `false`  there, so you can write following which also avoids the compiler error:

```
static int Div(int a, int b)
{
    int max = Math.Max(a, b);

    for (int i = 2; i <= max / 2; i++)
    {
        if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The part after the `return` in the loop was unreachable and unnecessary, so i've removed it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand why it will always be false after the loop, I mean, won't it just continue after the loop even if i found the divider?

Comment: Because if the loop could enter the part where you set it to true the method is exited because you return the value. The paet after a return statement is unreachable.

Comment: wait, If I return a value does that method stops? because if it does I understand what the problem is but I didn't know that

Comment: Sure, if you return a value from a method it will exit it. You have to ensure that all branches of your method body will return a value. I have ensured it by returning -1 as fallback value after the loop.

Comment: Ohhhh ok, Now I understand, so last question, if it stops the method, how do i make a method with multiple outputs?

Comment: You can fill a list, for a ample a List<int> and return that

Comment: I don't think I learned that yet so I don't need it for now, thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Nadavs2310: You're welcome. Consider to accept the answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `return` you exit the function immediately, no code beyond that line will execute therefore the lines after aren't reachable.

```
return i;
div = true; <<
i = max; <<
```

In your case, seems like you just want to set those values *before* you return.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
{
    return i;
    div = true;
    i = max;
}
```

The 2 lines after the return are never reached. Put them before the return. Also I don't think you need a div bool at all. It's redundant and can be optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

Proving whether an arbitrary method can reach the end of the method without hitting a `return` or throwing an exception is provably an unsolvable problem.  You can always construct a method such that the compiler would be unable to prove whether or not the endpoint is reachable, if you try hard enough.  However, it's important for the compiler to not allow any programs that have a return value but no reachable endpoint.

As a consequence of this, there are false positives.  The compiler does it's best to determine if a program has a reachable endpoint, and if it fails to prove it, it will error, even if you and I both know that the endpoint isn't actually reachable.

You'll need to change your code such that the compiler is able to prove that the endpoint isn't reachable, and the easiest way to do that is to remove the `if (div == false)` line and just always `return -1;`.  You and I know that `div` will never be true there, but the compiler isn't sophisticated enough to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

The return in the first if clause in the for loop is before the rest of the code, so there are 2 lines of code that will never get hit, these 2:

```
div = true;
i = max;
```

The reason they'll never get hit is because if the if statement is true, it'll immediately return, and if it's false it'll go to the second if.

Answer (score 0):

2 reasons : The line div=true is unreachable, the code after return is not executed. Replace

```
return i;
div = true;
i = max;
```

by

```
int res=i;
div = true;
i = max;
return res;
```

And the last 'if' clause has no 'else' clause allowing to return in all cases;